# Mostrar el elemento siguiente y anterior en un array

Tags: javascript

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código en codepen: https://codepen.io/SidPendragon/pen/vpxbOW

```js
var quotes = [
  '“All war is a symptom of man\'s failure as a thinking animal.” ― John Steinbeck',
  '“Strictly speaking, we do not make decisions, decisions make us.” ― José Saramago',
  '“The only way to deal with an unfree world is to become so absolutely free that your very existence is an act of rebellion.” ― Albert Camus',
  '“A lie is more comfortable than doubt, more useful than love, more lasting than truth.” ― Gabriel García Márquez',
  '“Try again. Fail again. Fail better.” ― Samuel Beckett',
  '“No man chooses evil because it is evil; he only mistakes it for happiness, the good he seeks.” ― Mary Shelley',
  '“The constant happiness is curiosity.” ― Alice Munro',
  '“Always do sober what you said you\'d do drunk. That will teach you to keep your mouth shut.” ― Ernest Hemingway',
];


function show() {

  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = quotes[0];
}

window.onload = show;

function next() {
  for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    var nextquote = //Aquí es donde me pierdo.
  }
  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = nextquote;

}
```

Lo que quiero es que al dar click en next se muestre el elemento siguiente del array pero no logro darme cuenta de como podría hacerlo. También quiero saber como podría hacerlos retroceder al hacer click en otro enlace.

Espero que porfavor alguien pueda ayudarme, lo agardecería mucho porque como pueden notar soy muy novato con javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Crea una variable para conservar la posición en la que te encuentras, cada vez que se pasa de una posición a otra se modifica. Te pongo como ejemplo la parte del siguiente elemento

```
var pos = 0;
function next(){
  pos = pos + 1; 
  var nextquote = quotes[pos];
  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = nextquote;
}
```

Para hacer lo de ir a la anterior posición es lo mismo sólo que restando.

Faltarían los controles para cuando se intenta acceder a posiciones fuera del array y demás.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías también extender la funcionalidad del array `quotes` añadiéndole una propiedad para mantener la posición actual (en mi ejemplo la propiedad `current`) y métodos que cambien a la posición siguiente (`next`) y anterior (`prev`) y que de paso devuelvan el nuevo elemento actual.

De esta forma tu ejemplo podría quedarte algo así:

```js
var quotes = [
  '“All war is a symptom of man\'s failure as a thinking animal.” ― John Steinbeck',
  '“Strictly speaking, we do not make decisions, decisions make us.” ― José Saramago',
  '“The only way to deal with an unfree world is to become so absolutely free that your very existence is an act of rebellion.” ― Albert Camus',
  '“A lie is more comfortable than doubt, more useful than love, more lasting than truth.” ― Gabriel García Márquez',
  '“Try again. Fail again. Fail better.” ― Samuel Beckett',
  '“No man chooses evil because it is evil; he only mistakes it for happiness, the good he seeks.” ― Mary Shelley',
  '“The constant happiness is curiosity.” ― Alice Munro',
  '“Always do sober what you said you\'d do drunk. That will teach you to keep your mouth shut.” ― Ernest Hemingway',
];
quotes.current = 0;
quotes.prev = function(){
  return this.current===0
    ? null
    : this[--this.current];
}
quotes.next = function(){
  return this.current===this.length-1
    ? null
    : this[++this.current];
}

function show() {

  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = quotes[quotes.current];
}

window.onload = show;

function next() {
  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = quotes.next();
}
function prev(){
  document.getElementById("ShowQuotes").innerHTML = quotes.prev();
}
```

```css
#ShowQuotes{
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span id="ShowQuotes"></span>
<button onclick="prev()">Anterior</button>
<button onclick="next()">Siguiente</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! tengo que aprender mejor sobre como usar "this". Muchas gracias otra vez!